# Sending an Outlook mail item from a C# application

Tags: c#, vba

In VBA I'm currently using code similar to the following to create and send Outlook mail items:

```
Function example()

Dim OutAppl As Outlook.Application
Dim my_email As Outlook.MailItem

Set OutAppl = New Outlook.Application
Set my_email = OutAppl.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With my_email

       .Importance = 2
       .To = "me@foo.com; "
       .Subject = "not so easy in C#"
       .BodyFormat = 2   'olFormatHTML
       .HTMLBody = "<P>" & _
                  "<BR>" & _
                  "<FONT face=""Lucida Sans Unicode"" size=2.5>" & _
                         "Hello SO" & _
                         "<BR>" & _
                         "</FONT>" & _
                         "</P>" & _
                   "</BODY></HTML>"           
       .Save
       .send
     End With

Set OutAppl = Nothing
Set my_email = Nothing

End Function
```

Where do I start in creating something like the above using C#?
Is there an outlook interops assemply that I can reference similar to using excel?

Comment: Do you have to use Outlook? It may be easier to use [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1fb84h.aspx).

Comment: Just putting your question title in Google leads to plenty of relevant results...

Comment: what are your exact requirements? There are [Outlook interop assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb652780.aspx) that you can use but as jrummell says: do you really need to use that?

Comment: @Servy agreed ... but I decided to put the question in SO. You can put anything in Google and it comes up with answers. If I want to ask a technical question to an expert audience then SO is excellent. The main criticism of my question is that it is vague and asking for opinion.

Comment: @jrummell - do all Exchange Servers have SMTP or is this something I need to contact IT about?

Comment: @whytheq You should not just ask every question you ever possibly could have on SO first because there are lots of experts.  There is an expectation that you will do your own research, attempt to solve your problem, and search for solutions that are already readily available before posting questions.  Once you have done all of that and still been unable to solve your problem then asking on SO becomes an option to consider.  Clearly you made not attempt whatsoever to try to solve the problem before asking the question.

Comment: @Servy - fair point. JMKs answer below certainly illustrates the small amount of work I _should_ have done! (although not really chasing points so sometimes happy to take a couple of -1 in order to get a quick answer)

Comment: You would have saved more time just using google.  Not only did you waste lots of other people's time, but you wasted your own as well.

Comment: @Servy ok - I'm currently looking into this subject via Google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question directly, the Outlook Interop library is just a few down from Excels in Visual Studio's `Add Reference` dialogue box:

[image: References]

And yes it works in the same way as Excels, you instantiate an Outlook Application object, and then more or less anything you can do through VBA in Outlook, you can do by calling the application instances equivalent method in .Net.

If you want me to add some sample code just comment and I will, but as jrummell says, why not just use `System.Net.Mail`?

Comment: Thanks for this post (agreed I should have done a _tiny_ bit of research before posting this question) In terms of `System.Net.Mail` is SMTP something that exists on all Exchange servers?

Comment: I am not an expert on Exchange servers but I would assume so, you should be able to get these of your IT Department, and then you supply these as properties of your `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` object, in the same way you would setup a standard mail client like Outlook or Thunderbird

Comment: There are tons of examples at http://systemnetmail.com/.

Comment: @whytheq 7 years later? 

Comment: @JMK I know! Just trying to be nice and looking for someone to up one of my questions and push me over that 20k line!